# Oracle INSERT: Column Value equal to Sequence Number's Nextval generated in another column

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence, sql-insert

I want to insert a row into a single table where one column's value is same as that generated by a sequence nextval for another column within the same `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO PRO.GTRANS_DEFS(IN_USER, GTRANS_NUM, SAME_VALUE) 
VALUES('JOHNT',SQ_GTRANS_NUM.nextval,XXX);
```

i.e. how can I replace XXX so that the `INSERT` will cause `SAME_VALUE` to take the same value as generated by `SQ_GTRANS_NUM.nextval` for `GTRANS_NUM`?

Reference of the other column 'GTRANS_NUM' in place of XXX has been attempted and is not allowed (Oracle 8i).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure of the behaviour, but could be worth trying :

```
INSERT INTO PRO.GTRANS_DEFS(IN_USER, GTRANS_NUM, SAME_VALUE) 
VALUES('JOHNT',SQ_GTRANS_NUM.nextval,SQ_GTRANS_NUM.CURRVAL);
```

Comment: Referring to `nextval` again would work too as the sequence is only incremented once per statement, but `currval` is a better pattern since it will work between statements in the same session too.

Comment: Using CURRVAL clarifies intent, whereas two NEXTVAL calls might trip people up.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my answer :-) I wasn't sure as my oracle is a bit rusty if curval in the same statement as a nextval will have the proper value or the "old" value :-)

Comment: @AlexPoole: Is this mentioned somewhere in the Oracle documentations or is it just an unspecified behavior? Can I rely on it to work in future Oracle versions?

Comment: @blerontin - [It's talked about here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/pseudocolumns002.htm#insertedID2): "Within a single SQL statement containing a reference to NEXTVAL, Oracle increments the sequence once ... for each row ...", and more relevantly for this specific example, the two paragraphs after the bullet list.